# Translate string in functions.php Loco Translate

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm adding a custom field for house numbers in the WooCommerce checkout like this,

```
function cfw_reorder_address_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['address_2']['label'] = __( 'House number', 'custom_string_translation' );
    $fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = $fields['address_2']['label'];
    return $fields;
}
```

I'm using Loco Translate to translate strings.

I don't know how I can get the `'House number'` string to show up in Loco Translate.

I've tried changing the `'custom_string_translation'` to e.g. `'woocommerce'` but subsequent syncing of the WooCommerce plug-in in Loco Translate doesn't result in the string `'House number'` to appear for translation.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this problem and found how to do it. Don't know if it will still be useful for you but maybe it could for others.

First, you need to write the child theme in the domain name field (and always do that for custom string you want translated) :

```
__( 'House number', 'child-theme-name' )
```

Then in Loco translate plugin Theme settings, you click on your child theme then click on create or "Modify the model" and use the sync button to update the .pot file of the child theme. You will then see the string you've added and you can provide context to help translators.

Once that's done you can add a new language if it's not done yet and here you will find your string to translate in the given language.